# CSS - Border for list doesn't show

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

html:

```
<li>
    <a href="">text<span></span></a>
</li>
```

css:

```
ul{
    list-style:none
}
li{
  float: left  
}
a{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

In chrome the right border doesn't show up:

image: i.imgur.com/OycFyOk.png

FF and Safari works fine.

Example code in fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/yrntrapk/

Comment: why do you have empty span-tags in there? if you remove them, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put display: block; to the "a" element:

```
a { display: block; }
```

Comment: or simply remove the empty span-tags

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Empty span tags on the HTML should be the quickest fix to this.